# The difference between print() and the code with sys.stdout.write(str(msg) + '\n') and sys.stdout.flush()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen a chunck of code like this :

```
def print_L(msg):
    sys.stdout.write(str(msg) + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between the code above and function print() without setting anything inside.

Comment: `print` doesn't flush unless specified (default is False), so that function is no different from `print(msg, flush=True)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to understand why someone else wrote a seemingly useless piece of code, the best way to get an answer is to *ask the author of the code*. (Or read an existing explanation from the author - for example in documentation; or in the surrounding text, if this example comes from a tutorial or textbook.)

Comment: My best guess - being charitable to the author - is that this code was originally written for Python 3.2 or earlier, before the `flush` keyword argument was added for `print`.

Comment: Hello steven

Yes but i mean sys.stdout.flush() has no impact on the code result, and thank you for get out the error i made in the post.

Comment: Hello Karl,

Possibly.

Answer (score 0):

for if you didnt know:
Unlike print, sys.stdout.write doesn’t switch to a new line after one text is displayed. use \n to do a new line. heres an article on flush. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sys-stdout-flush/

from what i've seen, there should be no visual difference - however i think that in earlier versions that there were some time bugs that flush() fixed - and there are probably different things happening internally in the python compiler

Comment: Hello Pink Z,

Frist of all thank you for you kindness for answering this question.
In fact, I've seen this article and run the code example on the website locally, from my observation, there is no difference with the sys.stdout.flush() which means no matter I add this line of code inside the program, it doesn't show any difference.